# Could I using firebase for custom RestAPI

Tags: android, firebase

I'm follow [this tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/) to making firebase Android client.

When I call RestAPI from Firebase, I only using Firebase URL and get a static data. How can I send data to firebase and get some dynamic data from firebase.

Example: I get 10 user have "Tom" in his name. I get all data from [User] node and keep 10 first user with the right condition.

I searched in this web but have no same question here.

Comment: If you are having problem with a specific piece of code, it is easiest to help you if you include the relevant code in your question. If you are looking how to query data, it is covered in the documentation [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

Comment: Let me read it first! Thank you for your response.